# How uber-go/ratelimit algorithm works?

Tags: go, rate-limiting

I tried to understand uber's opensource implementation of ratelimit, but a little confused

full code are as followings:

```
// Take blocks to ensure that the time spent between multiple
// Take calls is on average time.Second/rate.
func (t *limiter) Take() time.Time {
    newState := state{}
    taken := false
    for !taken {
        now := t.clock.Now()

        previousStatePointer := atomic.LoadPointer(&t.state)
        oldState := (*state)(previousStatePointer)

        newState = state{}
        newState.last = now

        // If this is our first request, then we allow it.
        if oldState.last.IsZero() {
            taken = atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&t.state, previousStatePointer, unsafe.Pointer(&newState))
            continue
        }

        // sleepFor calculates how much time we should sleep based on
        // the perRequest budget and how long the last request took.
        // Since the request may take longer than the budget, this number
        // can get negative, and is summed across requests.
        newState.sleepFor += t.perRequest - now.Sub(oldState.last)
        // We shouldn't allow sleepFor to get too negative, since it would mean that
        // a service that slowed down a lot for a short period of time would get
        // a much higher RPS following that.
        if newState.sleepFor < t.maxSlack {
            newState.sleepFor = t.maxSlack
        }
        if newState.sleepFor > 0 {
            newState.last = newState.last.Add(newState.sleepFor)
        }
        taken = atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&t.state, previousStatePointer, unsafe.Pointer(&newState))
    }
    t.clock.Sleep(newState.sleepFor)
    return newState.last
}
```

I realized this is a lock-free algorithm, but I know little about this topic.

appreciated if anyone happend to know this algorithm and offer me some answers/docs/blogs.

Comment: sorry, my question actually is trying to understand why this is a lock-free algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps consider updating your question then

Comment: yes, and thanks for advice.

Comment: This is not some fancy "lock free algorithm" it is just some CAS dance simulating a mutex.

Comment: is CAS not a part of non-blocking algorithm?